# Android Studio muestra errores en el codigo pero compila

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

De la nada android studio empezo a mostrarme muchos errores en mis proyectos de Android, crei que se limitaba al actual pero al abrir otros proyectos igual me muestra estos errores, a lo que intuyo es algo con las librerias de AndroidX pero al momento de compilar el codigo este funciona bien y ademas esto ocurre con proyectos anteriores que igual funcionan bien, he intentado muchas soluciones en internet y hasta hice una instalacion limpia de Android Studio pero aun sigue marcando estos errores.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te aseguraste de tener intaladas las APIs con las que estás trabajando? Es decir, tal vez tu código funciona solo con una _API X_ pero en su lugar tienes instalada una _API Y_ que es más actual.

Comment: @ricardo-dlc ya lo solucione, era un problema con android studio, tuve que hacer una instalación limpia, el error no solo era en ese proyecto sino en también en anteriores que funcionaban correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39953746/13851421 aqui esta la respuesta en ingles pero al parecer con las actualizaciones cambo el directorio de la carpeta de .AndroidStudio[version] C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.1, solamente haciendo una desinstalacion completa de Android Studio se soluciono mi problema